# Division of Positive Definite Matrix - Inner Product Space

Tags: matrices, inner-products, inverse, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I am trying to derive a simplified expression of something requiring some linear algebra.  I have gotten the stage below:

$$G = \frac{\mathbf{1}^H \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{1}^H \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{1}}$$

for completeness to provide more details:

$\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H$ and
$\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H$.

I have having trouble finding a simplification, if one exists.  I have looked at Sherman-Morrison formula.  Nothing is appearing to me and any assistance is appreciated.  My expectation is that after a simplification, a closed form solution to a problem I am working will pop out and will be greatly helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks. You are correct quesion is updated.

Comment: I may not have been complete above.  $\mathbf{A} = \left( I + \mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H\right)$ and $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H$.  So I suppose that means that $\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite and $\mathbf{B}$ is positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $s\in\mathbb C^n$. Let $\mathbf1^Hs=z$. Since
\begin{aligned}
(I+ss^H)^{-1} &= I-\frac{ss^H}{1+s^Hs},\\
(I+ss^H)^{-2} &= \left(I-\frac{ss^H}{1+s^Hs}\right)^2
=I-\frac{2ss^H}{1+s^Hs}+\frac{(s^Hs)ss^H}{(1+s^Hs)^2},\\
\mathbf1^H(I+ss^H)^{-1}\mathbf1 &= n-\frac{|z|^2}{1+s^Hs},\\
\mathbf1^H(I+ss^H)^{-2}\mathbf1 &= n-\frac{2|z|^2}{1+s^Hs}+\frac{(s^Hs)|z|^2}{(1+s^Hs)^2},\\
\end{aligned}
we have
\begin{aligned}
G&=\frac{\mathbf{1}^H \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{1}^H \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{1}}
=\frac{\mathbf{1}^H \mathbf{A}^{-1} (\mathbf{A}-I) \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{1}^H \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{1}}
=1-\frac{\mathbf{1}^H \mathbf{A}^{-2} \mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{1}^H \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{1}}\\
&=1-\frac{n-\frac{2|z|^2}{1+s^Hs}+\frac{(s^Hs)|z|^2}{(1+s^Hs)^2}}{n-\frac{|z|^2}{1+s^Hs}}.
\end{aligned}
You may simplify last expression if you want.

Comment: thanks.  This is exactly the perspective I needed.  I did not see the relationship.  Very helpful